# .htaccess redirect for one file

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

Somehow an erroneous URL of mine got indexed by Google. Which is:

```
www.example.com/index.php/
```

All I want to do is redirect it to the same URL without the `/` at the end. I have the below that seems to work well. I just want to double check this will only affect `www.example.com/index.php/` and nothing else such as an `index.php` in a subfolder or the like.

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/ /index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /index.php/ /index.php
> ```

This works OK-ish. It won't affect any other `index.php` in a subdirectory. However, it will redirect more than just `/index.php/`. The `Redirect` directive (part of mod_alias) is *prefix matching*, so the above `Redirect` will also match `/index.php/<something>`. And everything after the match, ie. `<something>`, is copied onto the end of the target URL. However, since you have omitted the trailing slash from the target URL, this will become `/index.php<something>`, which will likely result in a 404.

The fact that `/index.php/<something>` would result in a 404 (as opposed to a valid request) is probably a good thing, since you don't want to run the risk of `/index.php/<something>` (or the *target*) being indexed. However, you could change this so that `/index.php<something>` (where `<something>` is `/` or `/<anything>`) simply redirects to `/index.php` by using the `RedirectMatch` directive instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php. /index.php
```

The `RedirectMatch` directive takes a regex. The trailing unescaped `.` (dot) on the *pattern* matches *any* character.

If you wanted to match only `/index.php/` (exactly) then change this to:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/$ /index.php
```

NB: This is assuming you are not already using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) for other redirects/rewrites. It is advisable not to mix redirects from both modules, to avoid potential conflicts.

---

The `/` (or `/something`) on the end of a valid filename is called *additional pathname information* (aka path info / PATH_INFO).

If in the future, you wanted to block all requests that contain path info then you can add the following directive to your server config (or `.htaccess` file):

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

This will result in all requests that contain path info resulting in a 404.

However, bear in mind that some CMS use path info for routing the URL.